# How function passing works in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
class Test {
    x = 0;

    t2: T2;

    constructor() { 
        this.t2 = new T2(this.display);
    }

    display() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }

}

class T2 {
    constructor(private display: any) {

    }

    print() {
        this.display();
    }

}

let t = new Test();

t.t2.print();
```

When I run the above code it prints `undefined` instead `0`, can anyone please help me out with an explanation ? Thank you.

Comment: Cannot write a full answer at the moment, but you should totally read about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) | [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to TypeScript per se, but is rather a consequence of how `this` works in JavaScript. There are a variety of rules around how `this` context changes under various circumstances, you can [read more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Here, the value of `this` is determined by the receiver of the `print` method, which is in this case the object `t.t2`. This means inside the `print` method, `this` is referring to an instance of the `T2` class.

The print method then calls `this.display()` where again, the value of `this` is determined by the receiver. Since the receiver this time is just `this` again, it transitively carries over from the prior `print` call and is *still* the `t.t2` object.

And finally, since now we know that the `this` when you try to execute `console.log(this.x)` is actually the `T2` instance, we note that the `T2` instance does not have a property `x` and therefore we get `undefined` as expected.

---

Here is a code snippet demonstrating the `this` chain. Note how you can change the receiver of the `print` method and how that also changes the value of `this` within the method.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 0
    this.t2 = new T2(this.display);
  }

  display() {
    console.log("Does this in 'display' equal 't.t2'?:", this === t.t2)
    console.log(this.x);
  }

}

class T2 {
  constructor(display) {
    this.display = display
  }

  print() {
    console.log("Does this in 'print' equal 't.t2'?:", this === t.t2);
    this.display();
  }

}

let t = new Test();
t.t2.print();

// And note you can change the `this` by changing the recieving object:
console.log("Swapping reciever!")
t.print = t.t2.print;
t.print();
```